# Jfrog pipelines - how to cancel runs on repository updates?

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

Is there a way to cancel my active existing pipeline runs whenever a change is pushed to my repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set `cancelPendingRunsOn` for the triggarable GitRepo resources in order to cancel all the previous runs.

For example:

```yaml
resources:
  - name: my_app_repo
    type: GitRepo
    configuration:
      gitProvider: my_github
      path: myuser/repo-name
      branches:
        include: master
      cancelPendingRunsOn:
        newCommit: true
        pullRequestUpdate: true
```

You can enable this variable for new commit and also for pullRequest update. Please refer this documentation for more information https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/GitRepo